# Converting Nested For Loops To Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm having some trouble understanding streams. I've looked around and can't seem to find an example that matches my use case.

I have an existing nested for loop:

```
List<ObjectB> objectBs = new ArrayList<ObjectB>();
for (ObjectA objA: objectAList) {
    for (ObjectB objB: objA.getObjectBList()) {
        if (objB.getNumber() != 2) {
            objectBs.add(objB);
        }
    }
}
```

Alot of exampls show how to add `objB.getNumber()` to a list but not `objB`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` to obtain a `Stream<ObjectB>` of all the `ObjectB` instances and filter the `ObjectB`'s of the required number :

```
List<ObjectB> objectBs = 
    objectAList.stream()
               .flatMap (a -> a.getObjectBList().stream())
               .filter (b -> b.getNumber() != 2)
               .collect (Collectors.toList());
```