# Convert below imperative java code (nested for loops) to java 8 using streams

Tags: arrays, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

Below is the imperative style of nested for loops. I want to make use of java 8 Streams and other features to make it a functional style.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Java8 {

    public static final String TAILS = "TAILS";
    public static final String HEADS = "HEADS";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] coines = new String[11];
        Arrays.fill(coines, TAILS);

        for(int i=1;i<coines.length ; i++){
            System.out.println("Person :" + i);
            for (int j=1; j < coines.length ; j++){

                if(j%i==0){
                    System.out.print("Flipping " + j +"th Element from " + coines[j] + " to ");
                    coines[j] = coines[j]== TAILS ? HEADS : TAILS;
                    System.out.println(coines[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting Nested For Loops To Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36744975/converting-nested-for-loops-to-streams)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Java8 {

public static final String TAILS = "TAILS";
public static final String HEADS = "HEADS";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] coines = new String[11];
    Arrays.fill(coines, TAILS);
    IntStream.range(0, coines.length).forEach(i-> {
        System.out.println("Person :" + i);
        IntStream.range(0, coines.length).filter(j->j%i==0)
                .forEach(j -> {
                    System.out.print("Flipping " + j +"th Element from " + coines[j] + " to ");
                    coines[j] = coines[j].equalsIgnoreCase(TAILS) ? HEADS : TAILS;
                    System.out.println(coines[j]);
        });
    });
    
}}
```

Also I changed `if` in `filter` and `==` in `equalsIgnoreCase`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it

```
IntStream.range(1, coins.length)
        .forEach(i -> {
            System.out.println("Persion :" +i);
            IntStream.range(1, coins.length)
                .filter(j -> j%i == 0)
                .forEach(j -> {
                    System.out.print("Flipping " + j +"th Element from " + coins[j] + " to ");
                    coins[j] = coins[j].equals(TAILS) ? HEADS : TAILS;
                    System.out.println(coins[j]);
                });
        });
```